# Shape of image does not change after rotation with imgaug

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I'm rotating a picture the following way:

```
# Read in image
img = cv2.imread("pic.jpg")
height, width, _ = img.shape
print("height ", height)
print("width ", width)

# Rotate image by 90 degrees
augmentation = iaa.Affine(rotate=90)
img_aug = augmentation(image=img)

height, width, _ = img_aug.shape
print("Height after rotation ", height)
print("Width after rotation ", width

> height  1080
> width  1920
> Height after rotation  1080
> Width after rotation  1920
```

Why does the shape of the image not change?

Comment: You rotate the content, not the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image augmentation does not change the actual or physical `shape` of your image. Think of the original `shape` as an `window` from where you see the image or the outside world. Here all the transformations i.e., `rotations`, `stretchings`, `translation` or in general any `homography` or non-linear `warps` are applied to the world outside your window. The opening from where you look at the image, in my analogy the window, stays the same irrespective how the world outside i.e., the image changes.

Now it can obviously bring in some other region, not present in the original view, to the augmented view. Most often, newly introduced pixels will be black or it may depend on what kind of `padding` is applied.

In short, augmentation operations are not something like matrix `transpose` where the actual shape may change.

```py
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
augmentation = iaa.Affine(rotate=90)
img_aug = augmentation(image=img)
```

Let's see the images:

```
Original Image
```

[image]

```
Rotated Image
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @swag2198 for the detailed explanation. I now just use cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE to actually change the shape of the image.

Comment: I am curious, why do you want to change the shape of the image!

Comment: I appreciate your words but please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: As it can be seen in the rotated stack overflow image, it cuts off parts of the image. By changing the shapes via cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE , this shouldn't happen.

I'm using it for augmentation in an object detection model. If I don't change the shape, I get negative values for my bounding boxes.

Comment: iaa.Rot90(keep_size=False) will do what I want :-)

It makes sense that iaa.Affine(rotate) does not change the shape, because the image can be rotated not only by -90,90 and 180 but by any degree.